# Appending project grades

Tags: java, append, tostring

I still new to programming and need a little nudge in the right direction. The program reads from file and computes top score, avg score, and removes duplicates etc. Then adds their project grade to the end, project grades "N" is ignored and others are appended to end. I will add text file at the end of the post.

Instructions:

**XcelStudent**

> XcelStudent extends Student. An XcelStudent has a String instance
>   variable projectGrade, that gets set by the XcelStudent constructor:
>   public XcelStudent(String name, int id, int totalGrades, String
>   projectGrade) This constructor should call the super class constructor
>   to instantiate the Student instance variables.
>
> Override the computeScore() method. It should should call the Student
>   computeScore method to get an initial grade, and then add the
>   appropriate number of points for the project: 1 for a "C", 2 for a
>   "B", and 4 for an "A".
>
> The toString() method should call the toString method from Student to
>   get an initial String, and then append " project: " + projectGrade to
>   it.

I believe the first part of this is complete, and i have it detecting the four grades but im not sure how to append them to the end.

```
public class XcelStudent extends Student{

    public String projectGrade;

    public XcelStudent(String name, int id, int totalGrades, String norX) {
        super(name, id, totalGrades);

        int points;
        if(norX.equals("C")){
            projectGrade = "C";
            //points = 1;
            System.out.println(" project:" + projectGrade);
        }
        if(norX.equals("B")){
            projectGrade = "B";
            //points = 2;
            System.out.println(" project:" + projectGrade);
        }
        if(norX.equals("A")){
            projectGrade = "A";
            //points = 4;
            System.out.println(" project:" + projectGrade);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

}
```

Current toString and computeScore in my Student.java

```
public String toString() {
        String res = name + "\t" + id + " ";
        for (int i=0; i < totalGrades; i++) {
            res += " " + grades[i];
        }
        res += "\tscore: " + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(computeScore());
        return res;
    }


@Override
    public double computeScore() {
        double total = 0;
          if (numGrades == 0) {
            return total;
          }
          if (numGrades > grades.length) {
            numGrades = grades.length;
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) {
            total += grades[i];
          }

          if (total > topscore){
              topscore = total;
          }
          avgscore += total;

          return total / grades.length;
    }
```

Current output:(i know its not sorted)

```
Course cs161: 5 grades
 project:C
 project:A
 project:A
 project:B
Top Score: 90.0
Avg Score: 76.16
Course: cs161
Adam    2143  85 95 85 75 65    score: 81.00
John    1243  60 70 80 55 55    score: 64.00
Mick    1324  70 60 70 80 90    score: 74.00
Ellen   2341  90 95 88 77 66    score: 83.20
Jim     1234  50 40 50 60 70    score: 54.00
Lena    1423  99 50 90 90 85    score: 82.80
Leila   1432  60 70 60 70 60    score: 64.00
Mike    1342  60 70 80 90 99    score: 79.80
Ada     2134  90 90 90 90 90    score: 90.00
Helen   2314  89 79 99 89 88    score: 88.80
```

Desired output:

```
Course cs161: 5 grades
Top Score: 92.0
Avg Score: 77.26
Course: cs161
Jim     1234  50 40 50 60 70    score: 54.00
John    1243  60 70 80 55 55    score: 64.00
Mick    1324  70 60 70 80 90    score: 75.00 project: C
Mike    1342  60 70 80 90 99    score: 79.80
Lena    1423  99 50 90 90 85    score: 86.80 project: A
Leila   1432  60 70 60 70 60    score: 64.00
Ada     2134  90 90 90 90 90    score: 92.00 project: B
Adam    2143  85 95 85 75 65    score: 81.00
Helen   2314  89 79 99 89 88    score: 88.80
Ellen   2341  90 95 88 77 66    score: 87.20 project: A
```

File:

```
Adam    2143 N  85 95 85 75 65
adam2   2143 N   0  0  0  0  0
John    1243 N  60 70 80 55 55
John2   1243 N   0  0  0  0  0
Mick    1324 C  70 60 70 80 90
Ellen   2341 A  90 95 88 77 66
Jim     1234 N  50 40 50 60 70
Lena    1423 A  99 50 90 90 85
Leila   1432 N  60 70 60 70 60
Mike    1342 N  60 70 80 90 99
Ada     2134 B  90 90 90 90 90
Helen   2314 N  89 79 99 89 88
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you basically need to create a new toString method in XcelStudent (override it) and call the Parent's toString. Something along the lines of this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return super.toString() + "project: " + projectGrade;
}
```

For the part where you have to add the score, you can do so by again overriding computeScore for XcelStudent and calling the Parent's method and just adding the "points" based on letter grades. You can figure this out by just trying things out (hint: similar to the above toString method) - I don't want to do your homework for you.

Another thing that is side related is that you should be using protected/private methods unless you have a good reason to be making these methods public.